# duplicate table partitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, partition

I altered my partition scheme and function as usual to extend my tables partition. After altering, the following happened:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [pf_MONTH](varchar(8)) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (N'20181001', N'20181101', N'20181201', N'20190101', N'20190201', N'20190301', N'20190401', N'20190501', N'20190601', N'20190701', N'20190801', N'20190901', N'20191001', N'20191101', N'20191201', N'20200101', N'20200201', N'20200301', N'20200401', N'20200501', N'20200601', N'20200701', N'20200801', N'20200901', N'20201001', N'20201101', N'20201201', N'20210101', N'20210201', N'20210301', N'20210401', N'20210501', N'20210601', N'20210701', N'20210801', N'20210901', N'20211001', N'20211101', N'20211201', N'20220101', N'20220201', N'20220301', N'20220401', N'20220501', N'20220601', N'20220701', N'20220801', N'20220901', N'20221001', N'20221101', N'20221201')
```

As you can see below i have duplicated keys and partitions, which is crazy because it has nothing to do with the statement i executed (partition function above). Anyway i don't care to find how it happened i need to fix this with out losing data. When using the following query,

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(200) = N'kaltura.Consumption'

SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id) AS [object]
     , p.partition_number AS [p#]
     , df.name  
     , fg.name AS [filegroup]
     , p.rows
     , au.total_pages AS pages
     , CASE boundary_value_on_right
       WHEN 1 THEN 'less than'
       ELSE 'less than or equal to' END as comparison
     , rv.value
     , CONVERT (VARCHAR(6), CONVERT (INT, SUBSTRING (au.first_page, 6, 1) +
       SUBSTRING (au.first_page, 5, 1))) + ':' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(20),
       CONVERT (INT, SUBSTRING (au.first_page, 4, 1) +
       SUBSTRING (au.first_page, 3, 1) + SUBSTRING (au.first_page, 2, 1) +
       SUBSTRING (au.first_page, 1, 1))) AS first_page
FROM sys.partitions p
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
     ON p.object_id = i.object_id
AND p.index_id = i.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects o
     ON p.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.system_internals_allocation_units au
     ON p.partition_id = au.container_id
INNER JOIN sys.partition_schemes ps
     ON ps.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
INNER JOIN sys.partition_functions f
     ON f.function_id = ps.function_id
INNER JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces dds
     ON dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id
     AND dds.destination_id = p.partition_number
  INNER JOIN sys.database_files df
    ON df.data_space_id = dds.data_space_id    
INNER JOIN sys.filegroups fg
     ON dds.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
inner JOIN sys.partition_range_values rv
     ON f.function_id = rv.function_id
     AND p.partition_number = rv.boundary_id
WHERE i.index_id < 2
     AND o.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
   order by p.partition_number asc  ;
```

my partitions look like this at the moment:

[image]

How am i going to remove the duplicate partitions without losing data?

Comment: Please display query results as text, not as pictures, and include the actual query that produces these results. More than likely there's an error in there somewhere with a less than careful join condition that causes duplicated rows.

Comment: That's a lot. You can do a quick `SELECT *, [the rest] FROM ...` to get all columns in all rows, then identify what makes them different to see where the duplication comes from by going from left to right (some columns will have the same name, but they'll be in the the order of the tables in the query). For example, is the `file_guid` the same everywhere? Did you add files and/or issue the correct `ALTER PARTITION SCHEME SET NEXT USED` before altering the function?

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for the suggestion! the duplication comes from differences in the following fields : `allocation_unit_id`,`type` and `type_desc` in table `sys.system_internals_allocation_units`. I did the following in the following order : added filegroups. added files. altered partition scheme using next filegroup. Altered partition function.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I did the following in the following order : added filegroups. added files. altered partition scheme using next filegroup. Altered partition function.  I am thinking that maybe somebody has altered those again after i did..... Any suggestion for a fix?

Comment: example values for a duplicate: row 1 : `72057594225295360 1 IN_ROW_DATA` | row 2 :
`72057594225360896 3 ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA`

Comment: Well, as you can read in the docs, the row overflow data allocation units are there to hold data from variable-length columns that doesn't fit the maximum row size. You have 0 pages in all of those, but the query still includes them. Adding a `WHERE au.type = 1` should be enough to remove them (you only care about the in-row data anyway, not about LOB, overflow let alone dropped allocation units). If they were "never there before", it could be that the table scheme was altered to include a (larger) variable-size type that wasn't there before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add the filter(clustered index name) in the query and it will resolve your doubt. In fact it isn't creating any duplicate partition, logically it shouldn't. The reason you are seeing the result as it is because the same table might have non-clustered index. In that case the result will show you number of partitions = total number indexes * actual number of partitions.

Cheers!